# Download data from http using Python Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am new for PySpark and I installed Kafka single node and single broker on my Ubuntu 14.04.

After installation I tested the Kafka that sending and receiving data by using kafka-console-producer and kafka-console-consume.

Below are the steps I followed
Starting a consumer to consuming messages.

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic kafkatopic --from-beginning
```

Starting a producer to sending messages in a new terminal window.

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic kafkatopic
[2016-09-25 7:26:58,179] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
Good morning 
Future big data
this is test message
```

In the consumer terminal

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic kafkatopic --from-beginning
Good morning 
Future big data
this is test message
```

The below link from meetup.com produce streaming data

http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps

My requirement is how to collect the streaming data from http site to spark using Kafka. What is the transformation command to download streamin data?

After downloading the data I can find the count by city and other analysis for a particular time interval.

Comment: For this you have to put the data into kafka first, that can be achieved by kafka-producer script getting the input from curl http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps

Comment: @Green - where you able to figure out how your producer and consumer should work to achieve downloads? And how big was the data that you wanted to download? I am looking into a similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to process realtime streaming. The one i am considering is like below one.

[image: Realtime Streaming Spark Kafka Mongo HTTP Ajax Azmath Mohamad]